# need to send APNS push with http/2 java

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

Any help : I am using legacy code to send APNs push notification to iOS device. Now, the issue is sometimes push gets delayed and some times it is missed. So want to switch to http/2 which Apple supports now. I used jetty but it is not working fine. Any help or reference would be appreciable.

My code is below:

```
      public void sendHttp2Push(){
 String badgeCount ="1";
            HTTP2Client http2Client = new HTTP2Client();
            http2Client.start();
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("abcDistribution.p12"), "abc123".toCharArray());
            SslContextFactory ssl = new SslContextFactory(true);
            ssl.setKeyStore(ks);
            ssl.setKeyStorePassword("abc123");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2(http2Client), ssl);
            client.start();
     Request req = client.POST("https://api.push.apple.com:2195")
.path("/3/device/c9addc2f2ec6cdb9baafb5232bbc0f5d0e877ca1076619476d27c6a1ce5871c9")
 ContentResponse response = req.send();
            }
```

I am using the above mentioned code to send push notification with http/2 using jetty client.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in sending a remote notification is to establish a connection with the appropriate APNs server:

Development server: api.development.push.apple.com:443

Production server: api.push.apple.com:443